# How to show aggregate result along with the other columns in the same custom object

Tags: apex, soql

we are generating one Unique value(i.e., concatenating 3 fields) and storing in a text field,after inserting data into the object we may have same Unique Id in other rows as well ,so the requirement is we have to get aggregate of one field(No of cases sold) according to Unique ID and show in pagelayout along with the other columns as well.

**Query:**

```
SELECT  Unique_Product_Id__c ,sum(No_of_Cases_Bought__c) FROM CarSales_Boot__c GROUP BY Unique_Product_Id__c
```

By this I can only able to get two columns I can't include others.
Please let me know How to include and display remaining columns as well.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what *aggregate* queries are meant to do.

Comment: If you would like to add any further information, please **[edit]** your post to do so.

Comment: @kiran I suggest you post your controller code listing the fields you need to concatenate and showing how you want to pass them to your visualforce page. An aggregate Query will allow you to get Sum, Count, Max, Min, etc on fields, but won't concatenate them for you. You'll need to do the concatenation in your code.